# User maintenance page for some users but not all

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

We have an application with, 30000 site collections and about 70000 subsites, whenever we deploy a new solution we would like to make the entire web application read only for everyone, except for the uses that validate the solution deployment.

Please note that somes sites and libraries have broken permission inheritance.

Is there any way to do this, maybe with user policy at web application level?

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple options to set your web application as a `Read-Only` like

- Set Content Database as `Read-Only` using [PowerShell](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/01/set-sharepoint-content-database-to-read-only-using-powershell.html)
- Manage User Permission of Web Application in Central Administration.

[image]

**Although** the above methods will make your web application is accessible as `Read-Only` but **unfortunately,** you will not be able to deploy solution via any users even farm account.

**The recommended option is**

- Customizing an accessible maintenance page to inform the users **This site is under maintenance** as mentioned at this thread [For end users how to show a maintenance page to users when they browse sharepoint site in down time](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/202636/for-end-users-how-to-show-a-maintenance-page-to-users-when-they-browse-sharepoin)

Comment: But the idea is that some users can still access the site during the validation period.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't without managing the permission for other users!